# Set Excel cell colour value based on value in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

On the face of it this sound like a simple conditional formatting question but it's not.

I'm trying to build a colour chart using Excel and I want to know if it's possible to read a value from one cell and use it as the fill colour for another.

Let's say that I have a hex value in one cell with a value of #FF0000. I want another cell in that row to appear that exact same red.

It would be pointless to set up a rule for every colour (I might as well just set the cell colour manually) so I want to find out if there's a way to transfer the value using some sort of command or formula.

I have rgba (rgb) values too and I'm happy to split the R, G, and B values across different cells or even use Google Sheets instead but I want to avoid running any scripts to achieve this.

Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to use VBA to accomplish this

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad, I suspected as much. Thanks for replying anyway!

Comment: Hmm - can you post a short example of what you're trying to do? I have some ad-hoc macros I've already created, and may have on that can help you...